# Service End point Failure in Azure ML through SDK

Tags: python, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

I have been running a simple Linear regression model to predict prices and publishing its endpoint on the azure portal in free subscription trial.

I am facing problem in score.py program where creating the defination of init() and run()

The error that I am getting is 'list' object has no attribute 'predict' when trying to predict new observations on the published endpoint.

Please find the code of Deploy configuration

```
from azureml.core import Workspace, Experiment
print("Accessing the workspace from job....")
ws=Workspace.from_config()


# Get the input dataset
print("Accessing the Adult Income dataset...")
input_ds = ws.datasets.get('pricing')


# -------------------------------------------------
# Create custom environment
# -------------------------------------------------
from azureml.core import Environment
from azureml.core.environment import CondaDependencies

# Create the environment
myenv = Environment(name="MyEnvironment")

# Create the dependencies object
myenv_dep = CondaDependencies.create(conda_packages=['scikit-learn', 'pip','pandas'],
                                     pip_packages=['azureml-defaults', 'azureml-interpret'])

myenv.python.conda_dependencies = myenv_dep

# Register the environment
print("Registering the environment...")
myenv.register(ws)

# Creat an Azure Kubernets Service provisioning Configuration

from azureml.core.compute import AksCompute, ComputeTarget

cluster_name='aks-cluster-12'

if cluster_name not in ws.compute_targets:
    print(cluster_name,"does not exist.Creating a new one")
    print('Creating provisiong config for Aks cluster')
    

    aks_config=AksCompute.provisioning_configuration(location='centralindia',
                                                 vm_size='Standard_DS11_v2',
                                                 agent_count=1,
                                                 cluster_purpose='DevTest')
    print("Creating the AKS cluster")



    production_cluster=ComputeTarget.create(ws,cluster_name,aks_config)
    
    production_cluster.wait_for_completion(show_output=True)
else:
    print(cluster_name,"exists. using it..")
    production_cluster=ws.compute_targets[cluster_name]

# Creat the inference Configuration

from azureml.core.model import InferenceConfig

inference_config= InferenceConfig(environment=myenv ,entry_script='scoringscriptnew.py',
                                 source_directory=".")

from azureml.core.webservice import AksWebservice 

deploy_config=AksWebservice.deploy_configuration(cpu_cores=1,
                                                 memory_gb=0.5)

# Deploy 

from azureml.core.model import Model
model=ws.models['regression01']

service= Model.deploy(workspace=ws,name='regression',models=[model],
                      inference_config=inference_config,
                      deployment_config=deploy_config,
                      deployment_target=production_cluster)

service.wait_for_deployment(show_output=True)
```

And code of score.py

```
import json
import joblib
from azureml.core.model import Model
import pandas as pd

# Called when the service is loaded

def init():
    global predictor
    
    # Get the path to the registered model file and load it
    model_path = Model.get_model_path('regression01')
    predictor = joblib.load(model_path)


# Called when a request is received
def run(raw_data):
    # Get the input data as a dictionary
    data_dict = json.loads(raw_data)['data']
    
    # Convert dictionary to pandas dataframe
    data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_dict)
    
    # Transform the data
    # data = one_hot.transform(data)
    

    # difference of train and deploy

    # Get a prediction from the model
    predictions = predictor.predict(data)

    # Return the predictions
    return predictions
```

Can someone help me understand if the `init()`  function is not performing and if not what could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

The method which was mentioned in score.py is correct and the problem was with the way the model was called. In the **model** there is no value mentioned **predict**. Predict was missing and not mentioned in the model calling. Replace the code mentioned below with the existing code block.

```
output = model[0].predict(df)  this is the sample syntax
```

In the above syntax we need to mention the model as the list, and we need to assign that as the value.

Replace the existing model code with the code below.

```
from azureml.core.model import Model
df = pd.DataFrame('regression01', columns=features_name)
output = model[0].predict(df)
```

replace the above code in the place of below code.

```
model=ws.models['regression01']
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your answer , one question so instead of model ,I should use output in deploy configuration ,service= Model.deploy(workspace=ws,name='regression', models=[output],..

Comment: yes, need to use output

Comment: Hi Sairam have tried 

model=ws.models['regression01']
df = input_ds.to_pandas_dataframe()
output = model[0].predict(df)

service= Model.deploy(workspace=ws,name='regression',models=[model],
                      inference_config=inference_config,
                      deployment_config=deploy_config,
                      deployment_target=production_cluster) , still getting the error just to add model[0] without using model=ws.models['regression01'] was throwing error that there is no model[0]  , still getting the error as Model object is not subscriptable

Comment: model[0] should not be used here. It worked when I tried to reproduce. The same solution I posted. Once try to use model[] instead of giving 0